# Open a Bootstrap modal according to user choice when click on radio button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a Flask web app and I need to setup a scenario with bootstrap modals. I need to open a modal according to the radio button my user checked. My user will check a radio button then click 'OK' and I need a certain modal to pop. How can I handle this ? I used `data-target` for the moment.

My html code :

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalchoix" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Souhaitez-vous mettre à jour :</h4>
        </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="radio" id="referentiel" name="choixmaj" value="referentiel">
                    <label for="referentiel"> CHOIX A</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" id="transco" name="choixmaj" value="transco">
                    <label for="transco"> CHOIX B</label><br>

                </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>     
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalrefmodeles">OK</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: so if user click on yes only when you want to popup model or in both scenario?

Comment: I want to pop up modal in each case but not the same modal. If RadioButton1 checked when I click 'OK' I want to pop Modal1 and If RadioButton2 checked I want to pop Modal2

Comment: where is your jquery code ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I don't have Jquery for now because boostrap allow me to toggle a specific modal with data-target="#modalrefmodeles"

Comment: I know but you want different modals to be appeared with a click, you will need to make it dynamic with jquery.

Comment: Another thing, your radio buttons are already in a modal ? So, are you opening the same modal with a okay button ?

Answer (score 2):

With the code below you will be able to switch the modal according to the radio button value. This will be fully dynamic, even ids of modals are dynamic. Of course if you know Jquery well, you can do further stuff.

By default, I have removed the `id` from modal and set it dynamic with each click.

For now this code is working with radio button click. You can do it with another button as well.

In this situation the modal is only one, but you can set it different for each radio button value before appearing the modal. And you can set it according to your needs.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {

    var val = $(this, ':checked').val();
    $('div.modal.fade').attr('id', val);
    $('#' + val).find('.modal-body').text(val);
    $('#' + val).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Souhaitez-vous mettre à jour :</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          Hello

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" id="referentiel" name="choixmaj" value="referentiel">
  <label for="referentiel"> CHOIX A</label><br>

  <input type="radio" id="transco" name="choixmaj" value="transco">
  <label for="transco"> CHOIX B</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Javascript`.

Here I have two modals, with different `id's`.

The first modal id is `yesModal` and The second modal id is `noModal`.

Whenever you change your radio, `JS` is switch data-target from `yesModal` to `noModal` and visa versa.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio"]').forEach(cur => {
    cur.addEventListener('change', e => {
        const value = document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value;
        if (value === 'yes') {
            document.querySelector('#reactAccRadio').setAttribute('data-target', '#yesModal');
        } else if (value === 'no') {
            document.querySelector('#reactAccRadio').setAttribute('data-target', '#noModal');
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="formSubmit" action="#" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" checked> Open Yes Modal
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="no"> Open No Modal
    </div>
    <button id="reactAccRadio" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yesModal">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="yesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">If yes</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="noModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">If no</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!